# Function parameter is never for parameter to be used within JSON parse

Tags: javascript, json

I'm going through my code and neatening it up to make it easier to understand. In my code, I parse the same JSON at different points to get different data from the JSON.
I want to create a function which I call, and pass a parameter and it will return the information from the JSON.

My JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "Date": "11:10:02 28-02-19",
    "Number1": 2031,
}
```

The function I am trying to use is this:

```
function dataJson(key) {
  fetch("http://file/location/data.json?newversion") // supported in modern browsers.
      .then(res => res.json()) // parses into JSON. Fails if given improper json
      .then(data => {
        return data.key;
      })
}
```

and I am calling it within my script like:

```
dataJson(Date);
```

It should return `11:10:02 28-02-19` but I get the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Date is not defined

And in VS Code it tells me that `key` is declared but never read. When I have this in my script I would just use `data.Date` and it would return what I want.

How do I call the function with a parameter and pass the parameter into the JSON parse to return the data I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Date is not defined

`Date` is a variable name. You need a string. `"Date"`.

> And in VS Code it tells me that key is declared but never read.

`.key` doesn't refer to a variable. See also: [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

---

NB: `dataJson` has no `return` statement so it isn't going to return anything. See also [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Comment: `dataJson` does have a return statement. `return data.key`.

Comment: @JackU — Wrong. That return statement belongs to the arrow function you pass to `then`. It doesn't belong to the `dataJson` function.

Comment: That may be the case (which I didn't realise). However, the question was how do I pass the parameter `key` into `data.key`.

Comment: @JackU — See the first two paragraphs of this answer.

Comment: I have taken on board your commets (I didn't understand to begin with). I am not using `data[key]`. How do I return this? If have `return` in the arrow function I get `undefined`, but if I define it as a variable and try to return outside the arrow function, I get nothing? How should I return it?

Comment: "I am not using data[key]" — Yes, that's the problem, you should be.

Comment: "but if I define it as a variable and try to return outside the arrow function, I get nothing? How should I return it? " — See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)